# Symbolic link into /usr/bin in Mac Os Catalina

Tags: macos, editor, macos-catalina

In order to start Sublime Text editor from terminal in my mac, I used to do this:

```
sudo ln -s path_to_sublime /usr/bin/subl
```

and after this, I launched Sublime from terminal like this :

```
$subl
```

In this version of Mac OS (Catalina), I'm getting an error while creating the symbolic link :

```
ln: /usr/bin/subl: Operation not permitted
```

I think, they added a security layer... 
Do you know how can I fix this ?

Comment: I need to do this as well — and believe me, I do not want to change /usr/bin! But I'm using exiftool, and it has a hard-coded path to /usr/bin/setfile. So even though I have setfile in /usr/local/bin like a good boy, I can't use it from exiftool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thou shalt not mess with `/usr/bin`. Instead, make the link somewhere else and prepend its location to your $PATH.

```
% ln -s mything /opt/local/bin/mything
% export PATH=/opt/local/bin:$PATH
% which mything
/opt/local/bin/mything
```

and to make it permanent for your `zsh`:

```
% echo "export PATH=/opt/local/bin:$PATH" >> ~/.zprofile
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I created the folder bin/ in the folder local which I also created and performed this command : ln -s /Application/Sublime\ Text.app/Contents/MacOS/Sublime\ Text      /opt/local/bin/subl

Then I exported as you proposed. When  I execute "subl" in the terminal, I get an error message  ' Error loading syntax file "Packages/Text/Plan text.tmLanguage": Unable to open Packages/Text/Plan text.tmLanguage

Comment: Okay, this is a slightly different case than what you have asked in the question.  Another answer will be provided to you.

Comment: I need to do this as well — and believe me, I do not want to change /usr/bin! But I'm using exiftool, and it has a hard-coded path to /usr/bin/setfile. So even though I have setfile in /usr/local/bin like a good boy, I can't use it from exiftool.

Comment: @JanSteinman do you know the line number where it is hard coded… maybe that can be relaxed for macOS.

Comment: @RichardBarber, exiftool is a Perl script. I started crawling through it, but I'm no Perl expert, and couldn't fgrep my way to anything obvious. In any event, I had to re-boot, so I did it with a different boot disk, then I blasphemed and hard-linked it into /usr/bin, and re-booted off my normal boot disk. :-(

Answer (score 0):

The command to run the Sublime app would be

```
open -a Sublime
```

To make an alias of this, you would issue

```
alias subl='open -a Sublime'
```

To add this to your zsh more permanently:

```
echo "alias subl='open -a Sublime'" >> ~/.zprofile
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It works well. However I don't understand why you putted it in zprofile and not bashrc neither bash_profile ?

Comment: @ananass zsh is just the default shell in Catalina.